# Select Duplicated payments and invoices

Tags: sql, sql-server, phpmyadmin

Few months ago we had a bug with our payments.
What happened was our system somehow made duplicated payments from salaries and invoices and sent them to bank

Salaries have the same user_salary_id in 2 different rows if they are duplicated, and invoice payments happened 2 times with different ref_id

Total of 4 salaries paid should only be 2

View from **v_user_ledger_salary**

| user_profile_id | user_salary_id | requested_salary | user_ledger_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1111 | 32500 | 144.00 | 1 |
| 1111 | 32500 | 144.00 | 2 |
| 2222 | 32600 | 96.00 | 3 |
| 2222 | 32600 | 96.00 | 4 |
| 2324 | 32603 | 245.00 | 5 |
| 45423 | 32606 | 978.49 | 6 |
| 11151 | 32610 | 38.65 | 7 |
| 20000 | 32611 | 100.12 | 8 |

But invoices have a different reference number, reference numbers are "neighbors", with the same amount, meaning they are also duplicated

View from **v_user_ledger**

| user_profile_id | ref_type | ref_id | credit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1111 | INVOICE_PAYMENT | 999 | 100.00 |
| 1111 | INVOICE_PAYMENT | 1000 | 100.00 |
| 2222 | INVOICE_PAYMENT | 1049 | 320.50 |
| 2222 | INVOICE_PAYMENT | 1050 | 320.50 |
| 2324 | INVOICE_PAYMENT | 1051 | 666.23 |
| 45423 | INVOICE_PAYMENT | 1052 | 320.50 |
| 11151 | INVOICE_PAYMENT | 1053 | 10.64 |
| 20000 | INVOICE_PAYMENT | 1538 | 1392.93 |

View of t_invoice

| id(same as invoice_id) | biller_id(same as user_profile_id) |
| --- | --- |
| 234534 | 1111 |
| 235000 | 2222 |
| 235010 | 2324 |
| 235020 | 45423 |
| 235033 | 11151 |
| 235444 | 20000 |

View of t_invoice_payment

| id(same as ref_id) | invoice_id | amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 999 | 234534 | 100.00 |
| 1049 | 235000 | 320.50 |
| 1051 | 235018 | 666.23 |
| 1052 | 235025 | 320.50 |
| 1053 | 235043 | 10.64 |
| 1538 | 235444 | 1392.93 |

What I need is a query that will `SELECT * FROM v_user_ledger_salary WHERE rows have same user_salary_id but different user_ledger_id AND user_profile_id in (list)`

This should return :

| user_profile_id | user_salary_id | requested_salary | user_ledger_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1111 | 32500 | 144.00 | 1 |
| 1111 | 32500 | 144.00 | 2 |
| 2222 | 32600 | 96.00 | 3 |
| 2222 | 32600 | 96.00 | 4 |

And from invoices `SELECT * FROM v_user_ledger WHERE ref_id IN (SELECT id FROM t_invoice_payment WHERE invoice_id IN(SELECT id FROM t_invoice WHERE biller_id IN (list))) but ref_id needs to have same credit AND "neighbor" of the other ref_id AND user_profile_id IN (list)`

This should return :

| user_profile_id | ref_type | ref_id | credit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1111 | INVOICE_PAYMENT | 999 | 100.00 |
| 1111 | INVOICE_PAYMENT | 1000 | 100.00 |
| 1111 | INVOICE_PAYMENT | 1049 | 320.50 |
| 1111 | INVOICE_PAYMENT | 1050 | 320.50 |

*What I have is the list of user_profile_id 's that might have duplicated salaries/invoices*

Tables that are used **t_invoice_payment**, **t_invoice**

Views that are used **v_user_ledger**, **v_user_ledger_salary**

"Why is this a public question?" I have no idea how to search or in which words to search the answer for my problem, so please if you know how to solve this, or you have a link to other question similar to this one send it to me

Comment: Do you really use "tables" in your queries? Names that start with "v_" are usually views. More importantly, you need to provide DDL for the actual tables used - including the constraints so everyone can understand the relationships and the keys available. Lastly, make your code and your description consistent. You write "Salaries have the same ID" but the term "ID" is not clear since your view has no column named ID.

Comment: @SMor as DDL you mean table t_invoice (
id int(10),
biller_id int(10)) ect.

and i already gave all needed keys, what I mostly/mainly need is the queries or possible DML's to get the results I'm trying to get